# Method of Characteristics for a non-linear PDE

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations

I've been trying to work through some of the more difficult questions we've been given in class in regards to the method of characteristics for solving PDEs, but I've come a bit unstuck.

I've been asked to solve the following question;

> $$x^2 u_x + e^{-y} u_y = 2y u^2$$
>   Subject to Cauchy data $u(s) = e^{-s}$ along $(x(s), y(s)) = (s,1)$

So, firstly, I set up the following ODEs;
$$\frac{dx}{dt} = x^2, \frac{dy}{dt} = e^{-y}, \frac{du}{dt} = 2y u^2$$

Solving these three ODEs, I acquired the following expressions for $x$, $y$ and $u$...
$$ x = \frac{1}{A - t}, y = \ln(t + B), u = \frac{1}{C - 2yt}$$
Where $A, B, C$ are all constants.

From there, I used my Cauchy data, and set $x = s$, $y =1$, and $u = e^{-s}$.
Then, I set $t = 0$, in order to determine what my constants were.

I then got $A = \frac{1}{s}$, B = $e$, and $C = e^s$.

Now, rearranging my equation for $y$, I found that $t = e^y - e$, and using this, coupled with a rearrangement of my equation for $x$, I found an expression for $s$;
$$s = \frac{x}{x(e^y-e)+1}$$.

Then, all that remained was to put everything into my expression for $u$;
$$ u(x,y) = \frac{1}{e^{\frac{x}{x(e^y -e)+1}} - 2 y (e^y - e)}$$

However, this seems way too complicated,and I feel like I've made a mistake somewhere in my working.

I feel like my $\frac{du}{dt} = 2yu^2$ logic is kind of incorrect, and that I should be replacing the $y$ term here with $\ln(t + B)$, but even then, the integration becomes really horrible.

If anyone could provide some input, that would be fantastic. :)

EDIT: Yeah, I had made a mistake.

So, my equations and working for my $x$ and $y$ terms were fine, but my $u$ was bad.

To refresh, I've got that $y = \ln(t + e)$. Then,

$$\frac{du}{dt} = 2 y u^2 = 2 \ln(t+e) u^2$$
$$ \frac{du}{u^2} = 2 \ln(t+e) dt$$
$$ \frac{1}{u} = -2(t+e)\ln(t+e) + 2t + C$$

Now, using my Cauchy data, I have that $u = e^{-s}$. Setting $t=0$, we have...
$$\frac{1}{e^{-s}} = -2 (0 + e) \ln(0+e) + 2 \times 0 + C$$
$$ C = e^s - 2e$$

Then, using some manipulation of the equation I got for $y$, I can write $1/u$ as follows;
$$\frac{1}{u} = e^s - 4e + 2e^y (1 - y)$$

From here, I am assuming that I need to rearrange my equation for $x$ to make $s$ the subject, and then place that into the $e^s$ term, but still, this seems almost over the top. Is that really all I need to do??

Comment: Hi this is a fantastic question. Two things, firstly have you put your solution back into the original pde? Secondly, would an answer that solves it from scratch be of any help?

Comment: I had tried to, but it's kind of a nightmare trying to work through all those partial derivatives, which just keeps making me thing that I've made it far more complicated than it needs to be (and, more than likely, have made a mistake).

I haven't taken a calculus course in about a year, so I wouldn't really be sure how to go about doing it from scratch.

Comment: I am not too sure how you computed the $u$ from the derivative? did you use the y as obtained from your other characteristic equation? Since I get a different answer from yourself.. so show your working out for that step explicitly please :).

Comment: I'm not an expert in this, but you can't integrate $u$ the way you did, as you treated $y$ as a constant whereas it is $y(t)$.

Comment: Thank you, I have made the necessary amendments!! I'm still a bit stuck though.

Comment: The reasoning is correct. The final expression might not be super nice, but neither is real life (ever seen the change of variables in the Black-Scholes equation?). Anyway, you should check on wolfram Alpha that your result makes sense once you have the final form.

Comment: I did kind of run it through Wolfram, but I might try it again just to be certain. Thank you for the tips!!

Comment: You may make a mistake on understanding the initial condition of the PDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though it looks complicated, the solution is

$u(x,y) = \dfrac{1}{e^{\frac{x}{(e^y-e)x+1}} - 2 e^y(y -1)}$, which can be verified by substituting into the PDE.

The initial condition of the PDE is given by $u(s) = e^{-s}$ along $(x(s),y(s))=(s,1)$, which is $u_0(x,y) = u(x,1)=e^{-x}$.

The characteristic ODE are

$\dfrac{d x}{d t} = x^2$, $\dfrac{d y}{d t} = e^{-y}$, $\dfrac{d u}{d t} = 2 y u^2$,

with the initial conditions $x(0)= x_0$, $y(0)=1$ and $u(0) = u_0$ at $t=0$.

By solving the first two ODE, we obtain
$x = \dfrac{x_0}{1-x_0 t} $ and $y = \ln (t + e )$.

By substituting $y$ into the third ODE, we obtain $\dfrac{d u}{d t} = 2 \ln (t + e ) u^2$ with initial $u(0)= u_0$.

Solve this ODE, then, $u = \dfrac{u_0}{1- 2 u_0   (t+e) (\ln (t+e) - 1)   }$.

Obtain $x_0$ and $t$ from $x$ and $y$ respectively, and substitute $x_0$, $t$ and $u_0$ into $u$.

Thus, the solution is obtained, which is
$u(x,y) = \dfrac{1}{e^{\frac{x}{(e^y-e)x+1}}-2 e^y(y -1)}$.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I slept on the problem, woke up, redid it, and got a solution/working about the same as yours. Thank you!! My main mistake was treating $y$ as a variable, rather than a function of $t$, and then I'd just made some errors in substitution. 

Not important, but hey - thank you again!!

Comment: Hi @Jack, it's my pleasure that my answer helps.